# Problems working with the 'classic' library written by rxi

Tags: lua, love2d

Currently, I am trying to learn how to make video games with the Love2D framework. A tutorial suggested using rxi's 'classic' library to employ OOP.

Currently, I am trying to create a `shape.lua` file that describes a general shape (be it a circle, rectangle, or triangle). This is my baseclass which I would use to derive a subclass that describes a rectangle, called `rectangle.lua`. The `shape.lua` file would only handle the movement of its subclasses as these rectangles move across the screen.

However, this error persists whenever I try to run the `main.lua` file:

```
Error

rectangle.lua:16: attempt to index global 'Shape' (a nil value)


Traceback

rectangle.lua:16: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
main.lua:3: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Below is my `main.lua` file:

```
function love.load()
  Object = require "classic"
  require "rectangle"
  require "shape"
  require "circle"

  r1 = Rectangle(50, 50, 90, 60, 100)
  r2 = Circle(350, 80, 40)
end

function love.update(dt)
  r1:update(dt)
  r2:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  r1:draw()
  r2:draw()
end
```

And here is my shape.lua file:

```
Shape = Object:extend()

function Shape:new(x, y)
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.speed = 100
end

function Shape:update(dt)
  self.x = self.x + self.speed * dt
end
```

The `rectangle.lua` file is as follows

```
Rectangle = Shape:extend()

function Rectangle:new(x, y, width, height)
    Rectangle.super.new(self, x, y)
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
end

function Rectangle:draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("line", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

The end result that I want for now would be a circle and a rectangle moving rightward on the screen at the same speed.

If it helps, I'm also using the Atom text editor.

I would prefer the answers to stick to using the 'classic' library, so if anyone uses it, help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`Shape` is a `nil` value within the scope of your `rectangle.lua`

You `require "rectangle"` which executes the code in that file where `Rectangle = Shape:extend()` immediately causes an error for indexing `Shape`.

Adding `require "shape"` to `rectangle.lua` should solve this issue.

Another option is to switch `require "shape"` and `require "rectangle"` in your `main.lua`, but requiring stuff where you actually need it is nicer.

Comment: Thank you! it seemed to have fixed the problem. It is a weird library to work with though.